# How to make a multiple answer test at webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Heading I am trying to make my first website, which will be a multiple answer test and excuse me, if this question is too obvious.

During the survey/test one chooses options he finds correct, which are buttons with text/formulas.

I would like to highlight the one user has chosen, and if the person rethink and change his mind - he can do this, and the previously highlighted button will be unhighlighted and the new answer will be highlighted.
I have tried to represent by picture what I wish to obtain.
[image]

By now I was thinking of using html + css, to make this work, however or I do smth wrong, or html + css is not enough to do the job, or it is too hard, and more easy to use javascript( I did not use javascript so far, I only know that it is used for heavy logic/ in web sites that require some super stuff to be done on client side). I was thinking of doing everything by combining html + css, by doing a post or get requests. The reason why I thought of this combination - I try not to overcomplicate everything, and not "shoot the fly by the cannon". 
Here is the code, I tried to start from :

```
<button type="submit" value="res_1" > option 1 </button >
```

where css code is this (not the hole css, but the idea is clear that I was thinking to use active/target "pseudo classes"):

```
button {
    border: 2px solid gray;
}
button:active {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
button:target {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Questions:
If my idea to solve the problem as I stated above is somehow wrong, could you be pleased to explain why?
What is the best practice in this case?
What direction should I look, and which after coming problems should I be aware of?

Comment: You are most definitely going to need to use javascript to track the state of each button.   If you are new to coding and want to spend some more time, check out a front end framework like React, its the perfect time for you to learn it.

Comment: Dear @Alex, thank you for reply, I will start looking at it!  Could you be pleased to tell more precisely why tracking the state is difficult without javascript? I mean, I think radio buttons or other buttons can do that. Am I right?

Comment: @levgenii You need JavaScript because HTML can't do if/then logic, which is what you need to be able to toggle the CSS class applied to a button.

Comment: @Scott  You do not need JavaScript. You can use radio buttons for this.

Comment: Of course radio buttons can achieve the effect you want, but they cannot process the logic once you submit the page. You most certainly need Javascript or some other logic capable language for that.

Comment: @Alex What is the point of processing the data in JavaScript?

Comment: @Tim what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Alex I mean, why would you process the form data in JavaScript? What is the point of that?

Comment: Well I assume he is eventually going to want to submit the data selected by the user to some database and then alert the user that their survey was successfully saved.  Why would you not do that processing in Javascript?

Comment: @Alex I agree with the submission, although submission alone is best done using a plain HTML form. But processing that data is really a thing one should do server side. Otherwise, you expose your database credentials. Besides you can alert the user by using HTML and/or PHP. I think JavaScript is best avoided here.

Comment: @Tim yes of course, you would most certainly execute that logic on the server, but you still need to transport the model which represents the form for server side processing.  Anyway we are going beyond the scope of this question and more into the realms of application architecture!

Comment: @Alex That model can be transported through form submission. But I agree. Let us stop this discussing :P

Comment: Dear all, while reading a lot of comments a question born. Am I right that @Tim proposed the best solution to my specific problem that does solve it and I can continue to study how implement survey further, while Alex and Scott Marcus are proposing unified, more powerful/scalable to bigger variety of tasks approach? thank you people!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need JavaScript for this, you can just do this with hidden radio buttons:

```css
.question {
  margin: 20px;
}

.question input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.question span {
  
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid black;

  cursor: pointer;
}

.question input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
 
  /* The selected state of the answer */
  
  background-color: #72EB72;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="question">
    <header>What's a women called whom lost 90% of her intelligence?</header>
    
    <label><input type="radio" name="question_1" value="a" checked><span>Apple</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question_1" value="b"><span>Widow</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question_1" value="c"><span>Nurse</span></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="question">
    <header>How do you call a man who lost 90% of his intelligence?</header>
    
    <label><input type="radio" name="question_2" value="a"><span>Blue</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question_2" value="b"><span>Plumber</span></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="question_2" value="c"><span>Divorced</span></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need JavaScript to toggle the highlighted state of the buttons, but I think you are a bit too afraid of JavaScript. While it can be used for very complex operations, it can also be used for simple things as well.

```js
// Wait for the document to load all the elements
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Gather up all the buttons for question 1
  var q1 = document.querySelectorAll(".q1");
  
  // Loop through the buttons
  for(var i = 0; i < q1.length; ++i){
    
     // Wire up each button to a click event handler
     q1[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
       
         // check to see what class is currently being used for the button (selected or unselected)
         // and toggle to the other class.
         if(this.className.split(" ")[1] === "unselected"){
           this.className = "q1 selected";
         } else {
           this.className = "q1 unselected"; 
         }
       
     });
    
  }

});
```

```css
.unselected { background:#e0e0e0; }
.selected   { background:#909090; }
button { border-radius:20px;}
```

```html
<button id="q1a1" class="q1 unselected">Question 1 - Answer 1</button>
<button id="q1a2" class="q1 unselected">Question 1 - Answer 2</button>
<button id="q1a3" class="q1 unselected">Question 1 - Answer 3</button>
<button id="q1a4" class="q1 unselected">Question 1 - Answer 4</button>
```

Comment: Avoiding JavaScript when possible is really a thing which will improve productivity. Especially when working in teams. Secondly, why use JavaScript if you can do it in HTML and CSS?

Comment: @Tim Your solution is nice, but you are trading JavaScript for hidden elements, thus making the document structure more complex. I'm not saying you are wrong, but there is overhead in add more DOM elements as well.

Comment: That's true. Although, with templating techniques these days, I don't really see the disadvantage. Besides your solution will need much more code and/or HTML than this to support form submission.

Comment: How will my solution require more HTML than yours?

Comment: Depending on how you will store the data, you will need to add a form, **hidden** inputs, and logic to set those values. Or you will need to submit it with JavaScript, which will require a lot of code or an external library to support a wide range of browsers.

Comment: Not at all. My answer here was just a quick mock up to show how the CSS class could be toggled. I used buttons in the example, but since the OP doesn't want to allow multiple answers for a given question, I would use radio buttons, which store their value directly. Then, the form just needs to be submitted with a regular submit button.